# What is the jquery container?

Tags: jquery, containers

`$.trim` is a function of the jQuery container. Does the jQuery container simply mean jQuery object or does the container term have greater significance? Any clarification or advice is appreciated.

Comment: This is a low-level method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery offers several utility methods in the $ namespace. These methods are helpful for accomplishing routine programming tasks.
http://api.jquery.com/category/utilities/

jQuery utility method `$.trim()` is used above to remove any leading or trailing empty space characters from the user input. Utility methods are functions that reside directly in the `$` function itself. You may occasionally want to write a utility method plugin when your extension to the jQuery API does not have to do something to a set of DOM elements you have retrieved.